# Fact-based arguments for and against President Biden's plan to appoint a black female to the US Supreme Court as being like Affirmative Action

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, policy, joe-biden, affirmative-action

Wikipedia's [Affirmative Action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action) begins:

> Affirmative action refers to **a set of policies and practices within a government or organization seeking to include particular groups based on their gender, race, sexuality, creed or nationality** in areas in which they are underrepresented such as education and employment.

which seems to be an imperfect but fairly good fit to Biden's plan and goal in some ways.

Yet in CNN's [GOP senator criticized for remark about Biden's SCOTUS pick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XejUL2fPkJ4) Constitutional Law Professor Gloria J. Browne-Marshall ([twitter](https://twitter.com/GBrowneMarshall) with several other accolades) seems to argue against this being affirmative action while at the same time stating that black women may be underrepresented in the highest courts and certainly in the Supreme Court, and Biden's plan would be in the remedial direction, which to me makes it sound a lot like affirmative action *conceptually* at least.

It's possible that I'm simply not following Browne-Marshall's arguments carefully enough, that's just my first take.

**Question:** What would be the **fact-based arguments** for and against President Biden's plan to appoint a black female to the US Supreme Court as being like Affirmative Action?

Comment: This question [is being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6122/what-the-heck-if-anything-is-wrong-with-my-question-asking-for-fact-based-arg).

Answer (score 3):

The usual term for selecting a **political** candidate with a different background from other candidates is called [balancing a ticket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_balance), not affirmative action. Calling a Supreme Court nomination affirmative action denies the intensely partisan nature of of the process. This is no ordinary civil service appointment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you help me understand how nominating a supreme court justice is selecting a political candidate to balance a ticket? Where is the ticket in this case? Isn't equating  a candidate with a nominee a bit of a stretch?

Comment: I believe that nominating a supreme court justice is **more** like nominating a congressman or senator than like hiring a teacher or a civil engineer. If it was a simple hiring process, there would be no need for confirmation hearings, which tend to be intensely political in the present climate.

Comment: Okay, I can see what you mean.

Comment: The "ticket" in the phrase "balancing the ticket" is a set of candidates running for office together.  It doesn't apply to a judicial nomination.  "Balance" is certainly applicable, but I fear that "ticket" obscures the point you're trying to make.

Comment: @phoog, possible, but the principle applies also for successive nominations. Garland was a white male.

Comment: The principle of balance applies to successive nominations.  The principle of a ticket does not.

Comment: @o.m. Still is, too

Comment: @phoog In the modern political arena it seems pretty clear to me that the "ticket" includes all of the President's appointments, from cabinet members to Justices.  Once upon a time who the Secretary of Transportation was may have been largely irrelevant, I dunno, but today the fact that an openly gay man was appointed is a pretty big deal to the people Biden was trying to get votes from.  Similarly, a black female Justice was a really big deal to the people Biden was trying to get votes from.  This sort of "look who I'm going to appoint" has become very important lately.

Comment: If anything, they're becoming far more important than the VP itself, being the lion's share of the balance of the ticket.  The literal ticket, in who you directly vote for, may only include the President and VP, but in the people's minds they're voting for much, much more than that.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I've never heard "ticket" used to mean anything other than a slate of candidates in an election.  Can you cite an example supporting your assertion?  To be clear, I'm talking about the application of the word "ticket" to a president's appointments, not about the political importance of balance in selecting nominees.  Certainly the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_balance) doesn't mention appointments.

Comment: @phoog Wikipedia isn't a great source for evolving parlance.  That's just the literal interpretation, and what, as far as I understand it, it meant decades ago: precisely the candidates running.  But that's not the case any more.  Biden was going down in flames in the primaries, promises to nominate a black woman to SCOTUS, gets an endorsement, suddenly wins a state and goes on to become President.  That's because the "ticket" people were voting for wasn't simply "Biden/Harris", it was "Biden/Harris + black woman on SCOTUS + gay man as Sec. of Transportation + etc."

Comment: Similarly you can't ignore that Trump's claims and pledges of nominating anti-abortion judges and the like were a major draw to a lot of voters.  People respond to the putative policies and the whole shape of the (potential) administration.  Cabinet members and judges and Justices aren't just background effects that are of little relevance these days, they're major attractions for convincing voters.  They don't all only care about who is P/VP, they also care about these other positions and will vote based in part on the entire picture, not simply who is literally on the ticket.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I still haven't seen anyone other than you or o.m. employing this broader use of "ticket" or advocating it.  At the moment all I can see is that you're talking about how it _might be used_ rather than about how it _is actually used._  I agree that it might be used that way, but despite some searching I don't see any evidence that it is.  You haven't responded to my request to provide an example in support of your assertion.  Can you?